# Show patient_id, first_name, last_name, and attending physician's specialty

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

How do I use SQL to show patient_id, first_name, last_name, and attending physician's specialty?

> Show patient_id, first_name, last_name, and attending physician's
> specialty.
>
> Show only the patients who has a diagnosis as 'Epilepsy' and the
> physician's first name is 'Lisa'
>
> Check patients, admissions, and physicians tables for required
> information.

```
SELECT a.first_name ,a.last_name,a.patient_id FROM patients a
     JOIN admissions AS n ON a.patient_id= n.patient_id
    WHERE n.diagnosis='Epilepsy'
UNION 
   SELECT specialty
     FROM admissions AS n
     JOIN physicians AS p ON n.attending_physician_id=p.physician_id
    WHERE p.first_name='Lisa'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6;
```

patients table

```
patient_id  INT
first_name  TEXT
last_name   TEXT
gender  CHAR(1)
birth_date  DATE
city    TEXT
primary key icon    province_id CHAR(2)
allergies   TEXT
height  INT
weight  INT
```

admission table

```
patient_id  INT
admission_date  DATE
discharge_date  DATE
diagnosis   TEXT
primary key icon    attending_physician_id  INT
```

physicins table

```
physician_id    INT
first_name  TEXT
last_name   TEXT
specialty   TEXT
```

Comment: Please look at the formatted version of your post before you publish. Please read the edit help re formatting for code & quotes inline & in blocks. Please don't abuse formats. Ask 1 question. Please don't put something only in the title. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: You don't need a `union`; you can just join all three tables and put the conditions in your `where`-clause

Comment: Please either ask about 1 bad query/function with the obligatory [mre] & why you think it should return something else at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do & ideally a [mre]. But please ask about the former 1st because misconceptions in the former will get in the way of understanding the latter. [ask] [Help]

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution. You should also look at how data appear (mixed case) or even long descriptions (such as Epilepsy ABC).

```
select i.patient_id, i.first_name, i.last_name, 
 coalesce(p.specialty,'not provided') as physician_specialty --coalesce in case you decide to left join at some point
from patients i
join admission a
  on i.patient_id = a.patient_id 
join physicians p 
  on a.attending_physician_id = p.physician_id
where upper(a.diagnosis) like '%EPILEPSY%'
  and upper(p.first_name) = 'LISA'
```

Answer (score 0):

select p.patient_id,p.first_name,p.last_name,d.specialty
FROm patients AS p
JOIN admissions as a
ON p.patient_id =a.patient_id
JOIN doctors AS d
ON a.attending_doctor_id =d.doctor_id
where a.diagnosis ='Epilepsy' AND d.first_name ='Lisa'

--try this , worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
  a.patient_id,
  a.first_name,
  a.last_name,
  b.specialty
FROM
  patients a,
  physicians b,
  admission c
WHERE
  a.patient_id = c.patient_id
  AND c.attending_physician_id = b.physician_id
  AND c.diagnosis = 'Epilepsy'
  AND b.first_name = 'Lisa';
```

Comment: Code-only questions are poor. Please explain how/why this answers the question. Code snippets are for html/css/javascript questions, otherwise use a code block format. See the advanced edit help. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please before publishing look at the formatted version of your draft. [answer] [Help] PS Use tiny mnemonic table aliases, not a b c.